# C# Lists, create list object from a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, lambda

I have a list object like this

```
List<Site> lsite = GetSitesById(Id);
```

and the Site object is

```
public Site(int nId, string name, int Count)
        {
            Id = nId;
            Name = name;
            SiteOverrideCount = Count;
        }
```

What I need is `List<int> OnlySites=` which will have a list of only Site Id's

How can I get only id's from the lsite object, dump them in a list object and assign that to  List OnlySites

I am new at this, hope my question made sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Linq [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, e.g.:

```
var onlySites = lsite.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
```

This will produce a list of site Ids.

Comment: That worked like a charm, I am not very familiar with => operator, is there a good tutorial on this. It looks like a very handy feature.

Comment: @Sarah, this is a `lambda expression`. Have a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: Thanks, what about exstending it to return a sorted `string[]`? At the moment I have: `var listGroupNames = _PublisherData.FieldServiceGroups.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
 aryStrGroupNames = listGroupNames.OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();`. Can it be don't all on one line?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, `var aryStrGroupNames = _PublisherData.FieldServiceGroups.Select(s => s.Name).OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();`